# MySQL one to many get the no matching record

Tags: mysql

Im not good at explaining things so please bear with me.. Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to get the result of rows with no matching record to the table(tbl_personnel_documents) if I'm looking for the documents with a "YES" priority and based on their position.
Here's the structure of the table for employee:

tbl_personnel_info

```
id    name       position_id
1     John       1
2     Sharyn     2
3     Stacie     4
4     Kevin      3
5     Cristine   3
```

Table for Position:

tbl_position

```
id    position_name
1     IT Manager
2     Accounting Staff
3     IT Staff
4     H.R Manager
5     Admin Staff
```

Table for personnel documents:

tbl_personnel_documents

```
id     personnel_id      document_id      document_num
1      1                 3                111-222-333-444
2      1                 4                AB-CC-DD
3      2                 1                CC-BB-DD
4      4                 2                1-2-3-4-5
5      3                 4                C1-D2-X1-D2-G3
```

Table for documents name

tbl_documents

```
id     document_name       priority
1      Passport            YES
2      ROPC                NO
3      US Visa             YES
4      AUS Visa            YES
```

Table for document priority based on their position

tbl_priority_docs_per_position

```
id     position_id      document_id
1      1                1
2      1                3
3      1                4
```

In this case, John's position is an IT Manager which have no record of passport in the table(tbl_personnel_documents). And since the document Passport is a priority document for IT Manager but it is missing, it must display the result.
Im currently stuck in here.. I can't get the desired result.. Here's my code:

```
SELECT td.document_name
FROM tbl_personnel_info AS tpi
LEFT JOIN tbl_position AS tp
ON tp.id = tpi.position_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd
ON tpi.id = tpd.personnel_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_documents AS td
ON td.id = tpd.document_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_priority_docs_per_position AS tpriority
ON tpriority.position_id = tpi.position_id AND tpriority.document_id = tpd.document_id
WHERE td.priority = 'YES'
AND tpi.id = 1 -- John's ID
AND tpriority.document_id IS NULL
```

Please help.. Thank you

Update: I manage to partially get the result with this code:

```
SELECT td.document_name
FROM tbl_personnel_info AS tpi
LEFT JOIN tbl_position AS tp
ON tp.id = tpi.position_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd
ON tpi.id = tpd.personnel_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_documents AS td
ON td.priority = 'YES'
LEFT JOIN tbl_priority_docs_per_position AS tpriority
ON tpriority.position_id = tpi.position_id AND tpriority.document_id = tpd.document_id
WHERE tpi.id = 1 -- John's ID
AND tpriority.document_id IS NULL
GROUP BY td.id
```

Now my problem is whenever I change the position_id of tbl_priority_docs_per_position, I still get the same result.

Comment: This seems like a textbook or test question?

Comment: What is the "expected result"?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `left join` you must be very careful how you reference that table in the where clause or you might override the join. Here however I believe it is the sequence of joins:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM tbl_personnel_info AS tpi
INNER JOIN tbl_position AS tp ON tp.id = tpi.position_id
INNER JOIN tbl_priority_docs_per_position AS tpriority ON tpriority.position_id = tpi.position_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd ON tpi.id = tpd.personnel_id
                                        AND tpriority.document_id = tpd.document_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_documents AS td ON td.id = tpd.document_id
WHERE tpi.id = 1 -- John's ID
AND td.priority IS NULL
;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/625524/1)

```
| id | name | position_id | id | position_name | id | position_id | document_id |     id | personnel_id | document_id | document_num |     id | document_name | priority |
|----|------|-------------|----|---------------|----|-------------|-------------|--------|--------------|-------------|--------------|--------|---------------|----------|
|  1 | John |           1 |  1 |    IT Manager |  1 |           1 |           1 | (null) |       (null) |      (null) |       (null) | (null) |        (null) |   (null) |
```

Comment: Hi, I tried both of your code. But its not working. :(

Comment: sorry, it wasn't what I thought it was. I revised the answer. Note some joins are now inner joins.

Comment: Thanks for replying but still not working. I need to get the result if the priority is also set to Yes based on their position

Comment: I  have no idea what the comment above means.  "Still not working" is utterly meaningless too. Although I  do see you have now incorporated my earlier suggestion into the question. When you stabilize the requirements i may retry.